# How can I align some of the text on the left, and some of it on the right without using two labels

Tags: c++, qt4, formatting, qlabel

I want to use `QLabel`s to display some data in this format

> username:.....Erich Lancaster (without dots)
>
> Location:.......Wherever

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried a tab? Also, is there anything wrong with two labels?

Comment: A tab wouldn't suit this purpose. I'm basically displaying properties. I want the property name on the left and the value on the right. There's nothing wrong with two labels, but I was hoping to avoid it since I have around 7 properties I want to list, and I don't want to make twice that many labels.

Comment: Two separate labels sounds like the right approach, though: One immutable one that contains the field *description*, and one mutable one that contains the field *content*. Doesn't the form editor make this very easy to set up, anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like using the [QFormLayout](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qformlayout.html) would be the easiest.  Something like:

```
QFormLayout *formLayout = new QFormLayout;
QLabel *usernameLabel = new QLabel("Erich Lancaster");
usernameLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);
formLayout->addRow("username:", usernameLabel);

QLabel *locationLabel = new QLabel("Wherever");
locationLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);
formLayout->addRow("Location:", locationLabel);
setLayout(formLayout);
```